# why iterator defining as a struct but not as class?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I've some little question about STL iterator implementation.

- why iterator defining as a struct but not as class?
- what is the main reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is defined in the standard, **24.2** which describes the `<iterator>` header, which are `struct`. This choice was probably made because iterators provide access to container elements and making them `class` would be useless, the only difference being that `class` has `private` access level by default, whereas `struct` has `public` access level.

So there were 2 choices if declaring iterators `class` instead of `struct`:

- make all members `public`, which is useless since the same effect can be obtained by making it directly `struct`.
- make getters, which would provide unnecessary overhead and abstraction.

Comment: +1 for the standard reference. I wrongly assumed this was left up to the implementations.

Comment: Actually, iterator header describes iterator_traits and struct iterator, but concrete iterators may be classes or structures, 24.3-24.4 of standart n3337.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>It is an implementation choice.</strike> `class` and `struct` are almost the same in `C++`, the difference being the default access specifiers and inheritance, which are private for class and public for struct. So if a type has little need for private data members it may make more sense to implement it as a struct. But you can have exactly the same type implemented as either:

```
struct Iterator : IteratorBase {
  SomeType x;
};
```

is exactly the same as

```
class Iterator : public IteratorBase{
 public:
  SomeType x;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I gueesed this but i've some doubts

Answer (score 0):

Who says you that iterator is defined by struct? In standart there is nothing about it. Struct and class have only one difference - access to the elements as default. So, in struct by default access is public and in class by default access is private.

Comment: Actually, there is. See my answer.

Comment: This is implementation of iterator in gcc 4.6 (openSUSE 12.1)

Answer (score 0):

Like the best answer

class and struct is the same except the access.so use struct or class don't have many difference.

we know the C++ is include C

using struct seem simply and making a distinction between struct and class.

this is the define of iterator

```
struct output_iterator_tag{}
struct input_iterator_tag{}
struct forward_iterator_tag : public input_iterator_tag {};
struct bidirectional_iterator_tag : public forward_iterator_tag{}
struct random_accessl_iterator_tag : public bidirectional_iterator_tag{}
```